# How to set proxy in synaptic package manager?

Tags: 14.04, networking, synaptic

I am using Synaptic package manager in ubuntu 14.04. How to setup proxy in Synaptic Package Manager?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just open the Settings -> Preference panel:

[image]

and enter your proxy settings in the Network tab:

[image]

Comment: Good man! I have been searching for this work around! Thanks!